# How to remove Bing, from the universe?

Tags: browser, search, microsoft-edge, bing

I recently moved from Chrome to Edge. Great browser, except it wants to force feed you Bing.

I've changed my default search engine to Google. However,

1. I still can't remove bing from Edge homepage or new tab
2. Can't remove Bing from edge search engine list, remove button is not present.
3. Can't remove Search Bing in Sidebar.

50% of the times when I want to search something, Edge force feeds me Bing.

I've even changed windows host file pointing bing to Google. But Edge refuses to even load the page now, if I accidentally open a new tab, write down in the search box(not address bar).

I DO NOT want to see bing in my life. Not even on my phone, not even on my friend's phone or even on a stranger's device, because this search engine shouldn't exist. How do I get rid of it, from the world?

If you don't know about that, at least tell me how do I get rid of it from my life.

Answer (score 0):

Found the best solution! Search "Force delete microsoft edge" on Google Chrome, and follow the steps. It seemed to have solved the issue for me.

Here are the steps to remove MS Edge-

1. Open CMD with admin priviledge
2. type `cd %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\xx\Installer`
3. `setup --uninstall --force-uninstall --system-level`

Note: xx is your Edge version number. Navigate to `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application` to find the current version.

NEVER EVER RETURNING TO EDGE.